# how to get id when we are click the button using angular and ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

***I am using the below code and i am not getting id when i am clicking.***

```
<button ion-item  (click)="goToDrivePage()" *ngFor="let eventNames of eventType.events">
          {{eventNames.id}}
       </button>
```

any body help me to get id in the function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pass the id value to the function

```
<div *ngFor="let eventNames of eventType.events">
  <button ion-item  (click)="goToDrivePage(eventNames.id)">
      {{eventNames.id}}
  </button>
</div>
```

In ts file get the value

```
goToDrivePage(id : any){
     console.log(id);
}
```